# android - InApp Inventory checking loads a little bit long while my app launchs

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

I put `queryInventoryAsync` in `OnCreate()` of `MainActivity`, its checking SKU item a little bit long while my app launchs. How to make `queryInventoryAsync` checks SKU item before my app launch? in splashscreen or any other way.

```
mHelper = new IabHelper(this, getResources().getString(R.string.launch));
        mHelper.enableDebugLogging(true, "Proc");
        mHelper.startSetup(new IabHelper.OnIabSetupFinishedListener() {
            public void onIabSetupFinished(IabResult result) {
                if (!result.isSuccess()) {
                    // Do nothing
                } else {
                    mHelper.queryInventoryAsync(mGotInventoryListener);
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: Load purchase in Application class.

Comment: Thanks, i will try it

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in application class but you may not receive any callback from mPurchaseFinishedListener. As per docs, Your activity should override onACtivityResult method to listen it. So better to create iabhelper instance inside activity's oncreate(). While creating instance, just check if it is null, then create otherwise return. So for first time instantiation, it takes bit longer time.

Comment: its solved with this - `mHelper.queryInventoryAsync(false, mGotInventoryListener);`
i have onActivityResult, thanks